# How to get rid of java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error, development-environment

I know this question has been posted on this forum many times. I have checked my Manifest xml file and have been working on this for a couple days now. I have declared my Activity in the Manifest xml and this error still appears. How do I get rid of this run time error?

Logcat:

```
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.powersourceinternational.main/com.zooz.android.lib.CheckoutActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.carouseldemo.main.ZooZInvoice
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.carouseldemo.main.ZooZInvoice
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.zooz.android.lib.CheckoutActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
08-05 22:24:25.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     ... 11 more
```

Class:

```
 package com.carouseldemo.main;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ZooZInvoice implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * 
     */


    public void addItem(String string, int i, double d, int j, String string2,
            String string3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setInvoiceNumber(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setInvoiceAdditionalDetails(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Manifest XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.powersourceinternational.main"
      android:versionCode="4"
      android:versionName="1.3"
      >
      <uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
/>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/iconapp4" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>  
<activity android:name=".ZooZInvoice" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name="com.zooz.android.lib.CheckoutActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.carouseldemo.main.Manu"> 

            </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.carouseldemo.main.Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Checkout Activity Code in Main Activity:

```
public void onCheckoutClick(View v) {
        // create new intent CheckoutActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckoutActivity.class);
        // supply app-key on the intent
        intent.putExtra(CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_APP_KEY, "key");
        // supply transaction details (amount, currency)
        intent.putExtra(CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_AMOUNT, 500.00);

        intent.putExtra(CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_CURRENCY_CODE, "USD");
        // supply environment mode (sandbox or production)
        intent.putExtra(CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_IS_SANDBOX, true);

        ZooZInvoice invoice = new ZooZInvoice();
        invoice.addItem("item1", 1, 0.5, 0, "1", "good choice!");
        invoice.addItem("item2", 1, 3, 0, "2", "additional details for item 2");
        invoice.addItem("item3", 1, 2, 0, "3", "additional details for item 3");
        invoice.addItem("item4", 1, 8, 0, "4", "additional details for item 4");
        invoice.setInvoiceNumber("5512-FA");
        invoice.setInvoiceAdditionalDetails("Power Ups for user 12345");
        intent.putExtra(CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_INVOICE, invoice);

        startActivityForResult(intent, ZooZ_Activity_ID);

    }
```

I have already tried declaring the activity in the manifest as com.carouseldemo.main.ZooZInvoice and com.powersourceinternational.main.ZooZInvoice (even though the path way is the first one, com.carouseldemo.main.ZooZInvoice

How can I get rid of this error?

Original reference guide I used to write this code: https://app.zooz.com/portal/PortalController?cmd=resources

It's in PDF format, and the code is on the bottom of page 20.

Comment: Post your `CheckoutActivity` code

Comment: I edited my question. The CheckoutActivity code is there now.

Comment: Post your `CheckoutActivity.java`, please.

Comment: Yes, it is there. The CheckoutActivity is within the Main Activity.

Comment: There is only code for starting this activity, not a code of activity.  Post the class with the name `CheckoutActivity` (probably it is in a file with the same name).

Comment: It starts the activity and there is an activity. It's from ZooZ mobile payment systems. It starts an activity where you can implement credit cards and pay pal. There isn't a CheckoutActivity.java class. All the code required to make it work (which it does without the ZooZInvoice code) does work. I'm just trying to make it work with ZooZInvoice class. But it already works without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error in the `com.zooz.android.lib.CheckoutActivity.onCreate` method. It tries to cast an object of the `ZooZInvoice` class to some other class. You pass an object of the class `ZooZInvoice` as a parameter `CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_INVOICE`. 
Check in the documentation of library what type it is expected here and make your class `ZooZInvoice` inherited from this type or use the expected type instead.

Edit: You should use class `ZooZInvoice` from the library, not your own class with the same name.

Comment: 'CheckoutActivity.ZOOZ_INVOICE' is a string, and 'invoice' is a Serialization. They are a 'name' and 'value' respectively. How do I make it so ZooZInvoice is inherited from this type?

Comment: I posted the original reference guide link at the bottom of my original question. It's in a PDF format on the bottom of page 20 if this helps at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding this correctly. I'm a beginner.  Can you post the steps? Should I delete the class I made for ZooZInvoice?